# Force specific checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Forgive me for my ignorance, but I am just learning. I am using a specific javascript template for a checkbox selection. [Found here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/15/animated-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-svg/)

I am trying to force a specific checkbox selection, meaning no matter what the user selects, a specific checkbox is *always* the box selected. I have tried a few things and have not found any luck. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<form class="ac-custom ac-radio ac-circle" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>Question</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><input id="r5" name="r2" type="radio"><label for="r5">Selection 1</label></li>
                    <li><input id="r6" name="r2" type="radio"><label for="r6">Selection 2</label></li>
                    <li><input id="r7" name="r2" type="radio"><label for="r7">Selection 3</label></li>
                    <li><input id="r8" name="r2" type="radio"><label for="r8">Selection 4</label></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Sorry, just added it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use event change of all of the checkbox. When event change is triggered, then use javascript or jquery to check your target checkbox.

Comment: Note checkbox and radio is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try a bit of jQuery:

```
$("input[type='radio']").on('change', function(e) {

    // Prevent the default action
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#r5').prop("checked", true);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9s0gzxq3/

Just change #r5 to the id of the radio button you want to check.